# Coded UI: getcell not working for Wpftable having XamDataGridCustom in the hierarchy

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am new to Coded UI coding so need some help for the below problem I am facing.
I have a WPftable which has the below hierarchy in the UI Map:

```
this.UICommissionEngineMainWindow.UIXamDataGridCustom.UIRecordsTable
```

I need to read the cell value from the above table and cells have the below hierarchy:

```
this.UICommissionEngineMainWindow
    .UIXamDataGridCustom
    .UIRecordsTable
    .UIItemDataItem
    .UIItem2443Cell
    .UITextBlockText;
```

When I run the below line of code which has 'GetColumnName' and 'ColumnCount' method it works:

```
var myrecord = this.UICommissionEngineMainWindow
                   .UIXamDataGridCustom 
                   .UIRecordsTable.GetColumnNames();

MessageBox.Show(this.UICommissionEngineMainWindow
                    .UIXamDataGridCustom
                    .UIRecordsTable
                    .ColumnCount.ToString());
```

But when I try to retrieve the cell data it fails. I tried several ways but everytime it fails with

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotFoundException‌​: The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties. 
Additional Details:
TechnologyName: 'UIA'
FrameworkId: 'Wpf'
ControlType: 'Cell'
RowIndex: '1'
ColumnIndex: '1'
Search may have failed at 'Records' Table as it may have virtualized children. If the control being searched is descendant of 'Records' Table then including it as the parent container may solve the problem.System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

First Try

```
 this.UICommissionEngineMainWindow
     .UIXamDataGridCustom
     .UIRecordsTable
     .GetCell(1, 1)
     .Value.ToString());
```

ALTERNATIVE:

```
//GetProgramTablehas the Wpftable object in it
var cell = new WpfCell(GetProgramTable());
int row = 1;
int column = 1;
foreach (var data in dataitem.FindMatchingControls())
{
    var cell = new WpfCell(data);
    cell.SearchProperties.Add(WpfCell.PropertyNames.RowIndex, row.ToString());
    cell.SearchProperties.Add(WpfCell.PropertyNames.ColumnIndex, column.ToString());

    MessageBox.Show(cell.FindMatchingControls().Count.ToString());
}
```

ALTERNATIVE:

```
cell.SearchProperties.Add(WpfCell.PropertyNames.ColumnHeader, "Name");
cell.SearchProperties.Add(WpfCell.PropertyNames.Value, "2143");
MessageBox.Show(cell.FindMatchingControls().Count.ToString())
```

I am wondering when GetcolumnNames and ColumnCount works why the GetCell doesnt work.

Comment: I am sorry , I tried but am not able to format the code. :(

Comment: Can someone please help me with this ?

Comment: Have you reviewed the forum?  https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q475856

Comment: Yes I did but it didnt help because the forum is talking about DevExpress grid which am not using. I am just using VS 2015 and my table object hierarchy is this.UICommissionEngineMainWindow.UIXamDataGridCustom.UIRecordsTable

Comment: please post the full error message.  which control is not being found?

Comment: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotFoundException: The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties. Additional Details: TechnologyName:  'UIA'FrameworkId: 'Wpf'ControlType:  'Cell'RowIndex:  '1'ColumnIndex:  '1' Search may have failed at 'Records' Table as it may have virtualized children. If the control being searched is descendant of 'Records' Table then including it as the parent container may solve the problem.System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

Comment: There is still no full error.  you mention that you get a control not found exception, but it should list the variable name containing a reference to the not found control.

Comment: Can you see the error log I posted above? It was not allowing me to post the long error message so I had trim it down.